# Implementing LCM with Fractions

Tags: java, fractions, lcm

My code is almost complete but I must figure out why my "reduceToLowestTerms() "doesn't get implemented through my code and make sure every time i enter a Fraction it does it.

My code is a little long so I will be posting the link! 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0421493909708268ea9e

```
private void reduceToLowestTerms()
{
    this.switchSign();
    int i1 = greatestCommonDivisor(this.numerator, this.denominator);
    this.numerator = this.numerator / i1;
    this.denominator = this.denominator / i1;
}   // end reduceToLowestTerms

private int greatestCommonDivisor(int integerOne, int integerTwo)
{
     int result;

     if (integerOne % integerTwo == 0)
        result = integerTwo;
     else
        result = greatestCommonDivisor(integerTwo, integerOne % integerTwo);

     return result;
}
```

This is the code section that for some reason isnt being implemented throught the rest of my code 
How do i make sure all my fractions are in their lowest terms?

Comment: Probably no one will read through that much code. Please post the relevant code snippets here on Stackoverflow and some more background information (details).

Comment: kk i will edit this post!

Comment: @user3369798 cant understand the issue.Can u plz explain

Comment: @NiksTyagi When i run the code if i have a fraction that is 2/4 it does not reduce to 1/2 and im not sure why

Comment: i m slightly confuse.2 main method in the project.Fraction and assignment_1 class

Comment: @NiksTyagi I eddited fraction but my main class is Assignment1

Comment: i dnt found any issue in the 2 mthod that is pasted.How do u knw that it is not giving correct answer.Which method u use to c the result.The class is soo big to identify everything